# Information Disclosure Vulnerability

Tags: security-review, issue

Here is a security vulnerability issue of "Information Disclosure" reported by the Salesforce Team.

**URL**

https://yourdomain.lightning.force.com/aura?r=13&aura.DynamicComponent.getTemplateDescriptorWithExpansionBundle=1

**Notes**

- Parameter name: message (targetModule)
- Attack value: ' (Single Quote)

**Reproduction steps:**

1. Login to the application
2. Navigate to a record
3. Intercept the request using a proxy tool
4. Apply the attack value in the mentioned parameter ' (Single Quote)

[image]

We know the issue is the stacktrace disclosure, but since we are not part of the call nor of the error stacktrace, we reported this as a false positive after the first manual review. Now we failed the second review with the same vulnerability.

We then tried to reproduce it on a record page without our aura components at all, and the vulnerability is still there, so we suspect there's something wrong on the Salesforce side and not on our package implementation:

[image]

Can you help us understanding how can we prevent this vulnerability from happening? Because maybe we are missing something...